# Qgis load a set of excel points into a googlemap with only one point with real coordinates

Tags: qgis, convert, coordinates

I am working with a google map on which I want to attach a grid of five points. Only one of them has real coordinates in the centre, point O ( 8.32688E, 48,32933N). For all the rest only the excel coordinates with respect to this know central point. 
I want to plot the grid on the map and also I want to determine properly the coordinates of the other 4 points.

[image]

Comment: I seem not to get it. Why don't you just calculate the missing coordinates in Excel, export the table as csv and import it as delimited text layer with CRS WGS84?

Answer (score 1):

as Bernd V suggests, it might be easier to just add the appropriate x and y offsets in excel.

another possibility is to use the **Affine Transform** plugin (when installed, it's under **Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Affine Transform**)

You'd want to select all points except the O point - unless it's (0,0), in which case you should include it too.

Settings would then be

```
Selected points only
x' = 1.0x + 0.0y + 8.32
y' = 0.0x + 1.0y + 48.329
```